# How to always add caption element to images - even if empty?

Tags: captions

I want to add the caption ALWAYS to images, even if it is empty. This is my function to add the caption, but the caption element will not be generated when there is no content in it, how to add the caption element always?

```
add_filter('img_caption_shortcode', 'caption_shortcode_inline_text', 10, 3);
function caption_shortcode_inline_text($empty, $attr, $content) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'id'    => '',
    'align' => 'alignnone',
    'width' => '',
    'caption' => ''
), $attr));

// in this part I amtrying to always add the caption element but it doesn't work:

if (1 < (int) $width || 1 > (int) $width || $caption || !$caption)
    return '<div ' . $id . 'class="wp-caption ' . esc_attr($align) . '" style="width: ' . (10 + (int) $width) . 'px">'
    . do_shortcode($content) . '<p class="wp-caption-text">' . $caption . '</p></div>';
}
```

Comment: `if (1 < (int) $width || 1 > (int) $width )` this will only consider the width property.

Comment: This doesn't work, too: "if ($caption || !$caption)"

Comment: that statement will always return true :) did you try to check the width parameter? because your condition is basically  `if ( (int) $width != 1 ) { .... }`

Comment: I don't know id I understand you right - I want the condition always to return true. Because i always want to show the caption element, even when it is emtpy.

Comment: you could simply remove the `IF` and let it `return` sistematically

Comment: This is what i tried first but nothing happens.

Comment: What if you just set caption to &nbsp; if caption is empty string?  Also, have you confirmed the function runs on every image?

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio is correct. I see no reason this shouldn't work if the conditional is simply removed. Are you sure this code actually runs where you expect it to? Are you sure you filter fires where you think it does?

Comment: When is put "&nbsp;" in the caption field it works but i want to put "&nbsp;" automatically. I am sure the filter fires because when i edit the class "wp-caption-text" i see that it has changed.

Comment: Okay someone helped me, i have to use "image_send_to_editor" function and replace the output HTML. This way it works.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
add_filter( 'disable_captions', create_function('$a', 'return true;') );
function image_send_to_editor_2($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt) {

    $width = 'auto';

    if ( preg_match( '/width="([0-9]+)/', $html, $matches ) ) {
        $width = $matches[1] . 'px';
    }

    $output = '<div id="attachment-' . $id . '" class="wp-caption align' . $align . '" style="width: ' . $width . ';">';
    $output .= $html;
    $output .= '<p class="wp-caption-text">' . $caption . '</p>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    return $output;

}

add_filter('image_send_to_editor', 'image_send_to_editor_2', 10, 8);
```

Comment: It would be helpful to add some description on how the code works, thanks

Comment: The caption is just disabled and a new one is created.